# Expdp error UDE-22303

Tags: oracle, expdp

I am experiencing the following error, when I am trying to make an export to the database  using expdmp utility:

UDE-22303: operation generated ORACLE error 22303
OCI-22303: type "SYS"."KU$_STATUS1020" not found

Do you have any idea  what can cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> show parameter aq

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
aq_tm_processes                      integer     0

SQL> show parameter streams_pool_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
streams_pool_size                    big integer 0

SQL> show parameter db_cache_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_cache_size                        big integer 24G
```

Solution:

```
SQL> alter system set aq_tm_processes=1 scope=both sid='*';
SQL> alter system set streams_pool_size = 256M scope = both sid='*';
```

If you get any error like this:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-04033: Insufficient memory to grow pool
```

Reduce the db_cache_size:

```
SQL> alter system set db_cache_size = 12G scope = both sid='*';
```

and re-run:

```
SQL> alter system set streams_pool_size = 256M scope = both sid='*';
```

Now, you can run the expdp again without issues. Once done, don't forget to roll back all changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the user executing whatever statement you're trying to execute does not have the privilege to see/execute this explicit/user-defined type.

GRANT EXECUTE ON KU$_STATUS1220 TO PROTECT;

The above statement will permit the user "PROTECT" to be able to reference the TYPE. (Obviously, you'll want to replace "PROTECT" with whichever user you are using to execute the failing statement.

I'm curious as to whether this issue was seen during the execution of the Upgrade Readiness Tool (URT) provided by Symantec (now Broadcom) for upgrading the DLP software.  This is why I used the PROTECT user... (We'll also have to do this to our DLP_URT user too in our case. Not sure about yours).